'exist' returns true, but other commands like `fc` fail to find the file
if exist "./snapshots/!filename!.txt" is true, thus enters the clause,
but the fc (and other commands) fail to find the file anyway, printing out:
FC: cannot open ./SNAPSHOTS/*filename*.TXT - No such file or folder
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set passed=0
set failed=0
set nosnaps=0

for %%i in (./tests/*) do (
    set "filename=%%~ni"
    
    dune exec ../_build/default/bin/main.exe ./tests/%%i > "./results/!filename!.txt" 2> nul
    
    if exist "./snapshots/!filename!.txt" (

        fc "./snapshots/!filename!.txt" "./results/!filename!.txt" > nul
        if !errorlevel! == 0 (
            echo PASSED TEST: !filename!
            set /a passed+=1
        ) else (
            echo FAILED TEST: !filename!
            set /a failed+=1
        )
    ) else (
        echo NOSNAP TEST: !filename!
        set /a nosnaps+=1
    )
)

echo --------
echo PASSED: !passed!
echo FAILED: !failed!
echo NOSNAP: !nosnaps!

endlocal


I don't understand why this is failing... I suggest to change fc "./snapshots/!filename!.txt" "./results/!filename!.txt" by fc "snapshots/%%~ni.txt" "results/%%~ni.txt"

The solution is enormously simple:
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FC "u:/testing/q79095787/file1.txt" "u:/testing/q79095787/file2.txt"
FC "u:\testing\q79095787\file1.txt" "u:\testing\q79095787\file2.txt"
GOTO :EOF

where "file1/2" are simply identical copies of a random file.
Results:
FC: cannot open U:/TESTING/Q79095787/FILE1.TXT - No such file or folder

Comparing files U:\TESTING\Q79095787\file1.txt and U:\TESTING\Q79095787\FILE2.TXT
FC: no differences encountered

Conclusion:
\ is the correct separator for windows directories. / sometimes works, but inconsistently.
Hence - use the correct separator.

Whilst this may not be a solution to your problem, it uses correct syntax. It also does not unnecessarily use delayed expansion, or define and use an unnecessary variable.
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set /A passed=failed=nosnaps=0

For %%G In ("tests\*") Do (
    
    dune.exe exec ../_build/default/bin/main.exe "./tests/%%G" 1>"results\%%~nG.txt" 2>NUL
    
    If Exist "snapshots\%%~nG.txt" (
        %SystemRoot%\System32\fc.exe "snapshots/%%~nG.txt" "results\%%~nG.txt" 1>NUL && (
            Echo PASSED TEST: %%~nG
            Set /A passed += 1
        ) || (
            Echo FAILED TEST: %%~nG
            Set /A failed += 1
        )
    ) Else (
        Echo NOSNAP TEST: %%~nG
        Set /A nosnaps += 1
    )
)

Echo --------
Echo PASSED: %passed%
Echo FAILED: %failed%
Echo NOSNAP: %nosnaps%

EndLocal

You may need to change "./tests/%%G" to './tests/%%G' if dune.exe has not been designed for Windows OS quoting syntax.
